# C++ use non pointer values in object

Tags: c++, oop

I know this is super basic, but will a non pointer value hold its value when it is initialized within a constructor?

```
class foo {
    private:
        int bar;
        int cool;
    public:
        foo(int tBar);
        ~foo();
}

foo::foo(int tBar) {
    bar = tBar;
    cool = -5;
}
```

Or in other words, will bar hold tBar's value later on and will cool still be equal to 5 after the construction of the object?

Answer is Yes. I had a misconception that every member variable had to be a pointer!

BUT

When I use more complicated object types (like my own objects) it doesn't work this way. Why is that?

Comment: I don't think I understand. Their value will persist, yes.

Comment: Member variables wouldn't be terribly much use if they didn't hold their values.

Comment: Thanks. Just a concept that I didn't know about.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer instead of editing.

Comment: Or delete the question.

Comment: "When I use more complicated object types (like my own objects) it doesn't work this way. Why is that?" because there is a problem with your types

Comment: @Sopel Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is yes, the object will hold its value

Also I was using crappy objects. That is why they didn't hold value.